# How can i generate new name in the loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my Code:

```
 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
 {
    $elem=data;
 }
```

Here need instead `$elem` get `$elem1,  $elem2, $elem3` depending on the `$i`.

Example:

If `$i = 1` row **`$elem=data`** should been **`$elem1=data`**

If `$i = 2` row **`$elem=data`** should been **`$elem1=data`**

```
$('#div1').html($elem1);
$('#div2').html($elem2);
$('#div3').html($elem3);
```

Tell me please how make this?

**P.S**.: if you do not get the idea you can ask questions

Comment: Could you not just use an array instead? $elem[0], $elem[1] etc. It is possible to do what you ask, I'm just wondering whether there are easier alternatives.

Comment: @pburgess i know that may be use array, but its need for my knowledge

Comment: I think the second row in the example should say $elem2=data

Comment: is this php or js? you might want to fix your tags, or replace `$i` with `i` as it is confusing.

Comment: It looks more like jQuery this part `$('#div1').html($elem1);` o.O

Comment: SORRY ALL POST HAVE ERRORS TAGS. NEED HELP IN JS OR JQUERY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is JavaScript you can do what you want. Please don't ever use this over an array unless you absolutely need to. You need to use the `eval()` function.

```
$data = "worked";
for(var $i=0;$i<10;$i++){
   eval('$elem' + $i + '= $data');
}
alert(eval('$elem1'));
alert(eval('$elem2'));
alert(eval('$elem5'));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/begWG/1/

Comment: knowledge is always necessary to develop=) Thanks=)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample snippets, this code fits your purpose just fine.

```
var data = [1,2,3,4,5];

for(var i=0;i < data.length; i++)
{
    var elem = data[i];
    // other data manipulations
    $('#div'+(i+1)).html(elem);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmvAb/